New MongoDB Data Not Reflecting in Power BI: How to Detect Schema Changes Automatically?
Why is newly added data in my MongoDB collection visible when I refresh the database, but not reflected in Power BI after refreshing the data source? How can I ensure that schema changes, such as new fields or columns, are automatically detected and updated in Power BI?
What did you try?
I refreshed the MongoDB database, and the newly added data was visible when I checked MongoDB directly. However, when I refreshed the data source in Power BI, the new data and schema changes (e.g., new columns) were not reflected in my reports.
What were you expecting?
I expected Power BI to automatically detect schema changes, such as new fields or columns, and update my reports with the newly added data after refreshing the data source.

When you setup the Power BI then you can configure the refresh rate. Did you check it? Did you add new fields in all documents. You can also configure the number of documents to be scanned to create the schema.

I did  manual refreshes as i do not have powerBI service. However, the issue persists with new fields or columns that don’t automatically reflect after the refresh.
I confirmed that the new fields were added consistently across all relevant documents in the collection.
Regarding the number of documents scanned to create the schema, I haven’t adjusted that setting. Could you clarify where I can configure this in Power BI or MongoDB to ensure the schema accurately reflects all fields?

See Schema Options. Default is 1000 documents. Maybe have a look at Resample Schema Data with "FLUSH SAMPLE" or go to your MongoDB and drop schema database, defined at  schema.stored.source
